# Open Second TabBar view controller From Button Click of first sub view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, tabbar

I'm using 4 tab bar view controller. On submit button on first tab view controller to a sub view controller. I want to go second tab view controller as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: [@Nicolas Miari](http://stackoverflow.com/users/433373/nicolas-miari)  [@Nirav D](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6433023/nirav-d) Please tell  me current answer switching between tabview controllers   to sub view and sub view to second tab view controller

Comment: What do you mean by **switching between tabview controllers to sub view and sub view to second tab view controller**  ?, have you tried `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = youtTabbarIndex` tabbar index start from `0`, set index of tab you want to move

Comment: sir , i wanna click submit button and go to second tab as like image

Comment: Then on button action of this submit button simply add line `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = yourTabbarIndex` here `yourTabbarIndex` is index you want to move in tabbar

Comment: On clicking Submit(){ dismiss presentViewController} and then in tabVC's viewDidAppera(){ self.selectedIndex = 1} . You also need to write condition here.

Comment: thank god @RinkiNegi  you understand  what  i'm say but  please tell me viewdidApper() conditions

Comment: `self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
            //use delgate to identify that controller is dismissed and show your required tab bar

        }`

Comment: @ArjunYadav you have to create global boolean variable , whose value you  need to change on clicking submitbuttonClicked() and then in TabbarView Controller viewDidAppear(){ if btnTapped == true{ self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 }

Comment: @RinkiNegi don't you think delegate would be a better way.

Comment: @NiravD don't you think that the question should not be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Maddy thanks a lot to understand my question. i'm searching a lot on stackoverflow regarding that question. But couldn't find any suitable match regarding my requirement.

Comment: @Maddy Check the question title and duplicate question both are same if this question edited with other requirement than Its possible to open the question

Comment: @ArjunYadav i have created a sample, hopefully it will solve your problem. https://github.com/Maddybarak/SwiftyTabBar/

Comment: @Maddy thanks dear , this work perfectly ...